# Firebase : How to put the currently returned node's key into a POJO as a field

Tags: android, firebase, hashmap, firebase-realtime-database

**I hope to improve the title of this question**

Assume I have the following.

```
abstract class getMessage {
      public getMessage(String k) {
         get(k);
      }

      public abstract void Success(Message message);
      private void get(final String k) {
         DatabaseReference r    = DB.child("chat/messages/" + k);
         r.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot d) {
               Message msg = d.getValue(Message.class);
               Success(msg);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError e) {
               Log.w("Get Message", e.toException());
            }
         });
      }
   }
```

The **Message** Class has a field "messageid", which should be the key of the returned node, but the returned data is the child of this key.

---

Before this, I inserted the fields with :

```
Long time         = d.child("time").getValue();
Long String       = d.child("text").getValue();
Long messageid    = d.getKey();
Message message   = new Message(time, messageid, text);
```

As you can see above, I was able to take the "messageid" and put it into the **Message** object, but using the new approach(**First Code block**), I don't know how to do this.

Is it possible?

**EDIT**

**THE Message Class :**

```
public class Message implements Serializable {
   private String  name;
   private String  msg;
   private String  icon;
   private String  recipient;
   private String  sender;
   private String  shared;
   private Boolean group;
   private Object  time;
   private String  messageid;
   private Boolean local;
   private Boolean delivered;
   private Boolean read;
   private HashMap<String, Boolean> allowed;

   private String file;
   private Boolean attachment;
   private Boolean state;


   public Message(String Name, String Msg, String Recipient, String Sender, String Shared, Boolean Group, String Icon,
                  Object Time, String Messageid, Boolean Local, Boolean Delivered, Boolean Read,
                  HashMap<String, Boolean> Allowed, String File, Boolean Attachment, Boolean State) {
      name = Name;
      msg = Msg;
      recipient = Recipient;
      sender = Sender;
      shared = Shared;
      group = Group;
      time = Time;
      icon = Icon;
      messageid = Messageid;
      local = Local;
      delivered = Delivered;
      read = Read;
      file  = File;
      allowed   = Allowed;
      attachment    = Attachment;
      state         = State;
   }

   public Message() {

   }

   public Boolean getAttachment() {
      return attachment;
   }

   public Boolean getState() {
      return state;
   }

   public HashMap<String, Boolean> getAllowed() {
      return allowed;
   }

   public String getFile() {
      return file;
   }

   public Boolean getDelivered() {
      return delivered;
   }

   public Boolean getRead() {
      return read;
   }

   public Boolean getLocal() {
      return local;
   }

   public String getMessageid() {
      return messageid;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public Object getTime() {
      return time;
   }

   public String getMsg() {
      return msg;
   }

   public Boolean getGroup() {
      return group;
   }

   public String getRecipient() {
      return recipient;
   }

   public String getSender() {
      return sender;
   }

   public String getShared() {
      return shared;
   }

   public String getIcon() {
      return icon;
   }
}
```

Comment: can you post your `Message` class? the `DataSnapshot.getKey()` returns a String so it's quite weird that you are able to do this `Long messageid = d.getKey();`

Comment: @Wilik its a bit long, apologies, but will put it just now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by adding a setter to the `Message` class and then call that method to set the key.

```
public void setMessageid(String messageId) {
    this.messageid = messageId;
}
```

inside the `onDataChange` method

```
Message msg = d.getValue(Message.class);
msg.setMessageId(d.getKey());
Success(msg);
```